# sticky footer and paginator in mat-table

Tags: angular-material, footer, sticky-footer, angular-material-table

I have a table inside a form with 2 buttons. place 2 buttons in the footer section of the material table after the paginator option. keep the paginator option and footer sticky

this is the expected design[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY62A.png)